# Word for a "decorated item"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, er-ee

Is there a single word for something that is subject to a decoration? Is it something like "decoree"?

EDIT: I want to give an explanation what I need this word for. I am currently developing a software that among other things renders text. Just think of something like [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). Everything that is visible on screen is called a *Box*. These boxes can be "decorated" by adding accents, over- or underlines etc. Now I need variable names for the box that is decorated as well as the "subject" of the decoration. Because I have loads of these boxes, box is too ambiguous. I thought of "decoree" just as we call a program being debugged the [*debuggee*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/debuggee). As I am not a native speaker, I was just wondering if there's a word that describes what I mean and doesn't sound weird to a native speaker who later reads my code.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a word, as the thing that is subject to decoration is quite typically identified by its name. A decorated tree will be referred to as, well, a tree. A decorated car is a car. So there is no need for something like *decoree*, and thus it does not exist. And since so many different things can be decorated, there is no hypernym for them, either. A car and a tree can only be summed up as *stuff*.

Comment: Such things could both be figuratively referred to as *canvases*, but even allowing that such figurative use is common enough, it seems too much a stretch: A phrase could use *canvas* in such a way and have everything clear, but if I just said "I decorated several canvases" that would not be interpreted as "I decorated several things subject to decoration".

Comment: A thing that is decorated is an embellished piece; using the term 'embellishment' is clearly understood by English native speakers.  Axel, if you are requesting names for the style of embellishments, they exists too -good luck

Comment: Come up with [nonce word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word)s if you really need it. For example: decoratee or decoratable.

Comment: @ermanen: now that's it. Kris even added a reference to its usage in the programming world. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Decoratable is used in programming world also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the programming world, the term *decoratee* is in use.

> Decorators are functions that wrap around other functions.  This allows decorators to execute code before and after a function is called. A decorator takes a function object as an argument (which is called the **decoratee**) and returns a new function object that will be executed in its place. [[Matt Johnson, *Decorators in Python*](http://satchamo.com/python.pdf)]

Answer (score 0):

Anything really can be subject to decoration.  Wall, sheet of paper, a dress, a table, whatever.  If you put the word *ornate* before any of these nouns one would gather that it is heavily decorated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be *[ornamented](http://dict.hinkhoj.com/words/meaning-of-ORNAMENT-in-hindi.html)*. You can use it for decorated items.

Answer (score 0):

The box was [bedizened](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bedizen) with an abundance of pink pearls and blue sapphires.

> Dress up or decorate gaudily 'a uniform bedizened with resplendent medals'

Also see [bedizenment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bedizenment).

> That which bedizens.